# CodeIgniter process a function but stay on the current page

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

I have a website layout divided into the multiple partial files. One of them is a view which seats in the sidebar. There is a link in it (Facebook Connect), when I press it, it call a specific function, when it's completed without any errors, i received a blank page.

How to program it, so after processing a function inside another Controller, it will stay at the same url ?

Here is a visual. Imagine that I'am on this url `http://localhost/web/blog`. Here, on that page, i have a sidebar loaded with a link in it, which once it's pressed it will process a function. The url of this link in the sidebar is `http://localhost/web/member/facebook_login`.
After it's done, it should stay on the same url `http://localhost/web/blog` instead of `/web/member/facebook_login`.

Is it possible to do it without using a `redirect()` function ? So it will stay on the same page whenever you are, if your url is `/web/home` or `web/about-us` etc. ?

Thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why using the HTTP referrer is a bad idea, i just explained in my comment.

> The url of this link in the sidebar is `http://localhost/web/member/facebook_login`

Then you should put the URL of the current page into that link, as a parameter:

`http://localhost/web/member/facebook_login?go_back_url={url_of_the_current_page}`

Then, after successful login, you can use the value of the parameter `go_back_url` to redirect back to the address it contains.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be a better solution I guess. Will try it out soon. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Found it!
Instead of using `redirect('somecontroller/somefunction/someslug')` you can use `user_agent` library.

```
redirect($this->agent->referrer());
```

Along by loading the `user_agent` library to make it possible `$this->load->library('user_agent');`

Comment: That is an extremely bad idea.

Comment: That’s true, tereško – but you should at least tell him _why_. It’s a bad idea, because a browser does not have to send a referrer value, or it can be set to something else (f.e. some user firewalls etc. do this). __The HTTP referrer is not reliable__ – that’s an absolut basic rule of web programming.

Comment: thank your for your note. I thought if it works as it should, then it's ok.